# Convert audio to string (just like we can convert image to Base64String)?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been using `Convert.ToBase64String(...)` to embed images into XML documents, and I now would like to embed an audio recording into an XML file.

Is there a way we can convert an audio file into some kind of string the same way we can convert an image to a string to be embedded into an XML file?

Comment: so, what is stopping you to convert audio file to base64 string ?

Comment: All files are just a sequence of bytes. So, base64-encoding an audio file is no different from base64-encoding an image file.

Comment: Visual Studio keeps showing a red squiggly but with no error information. I just assumed I was going about it the wrong way, and I could not find anything when I searched "convert audio file to string C#"

Comment: @Aeron: Show your code, then! :-)

Comment: *I just assumed I was going about it the wrong way*, if you were we wouldn't know because you haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, I am going to edit to include my code now.

Comment: You convert in in exactly the same way you do an image. That is you convert it to a sequence of bytes which you then base64 encode.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to read in the audio file as binary [System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%5d) and then make your conversion [System.Convert.ToBase64String()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

At first I went with your original thought on converting to string via Convert.ToBase64String(... but at least in my example I had trouble converting back to bytes and playing the sound with that method.

Here is a quick sample that works here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filename = @"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Ping.wav";
    string tmp = "";
    SoundPlayer sp;
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        byte[] filebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        Console.WriteLine("filebytes length: " + filebytes.Length);
        //tmp = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(filename), Base64FormattingOptions.None);
        tmp = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
        Console.Write("string length: " + tmp.Length);
        //sp = new SoundPlayer(new MemoryStream(filebytes));
        //sp.Play();

        Console.ReadLine();

        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(tmp);//Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tmp);
        Console.WriteLine("bytes length: " + bytes.Length);
        sp = new SoundPlayer(new MemoryStream(bytes));
        sp.Play();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```